# JPA merge() on detached entity makes insert when it exists

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i use JPA with hibernate provider. heres my part code:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(xxxPK.class)
@NamedQueries({
...
})
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class xxx extends AbstractEntity {

public static final String GET_TRADES = "getInstruments";
public static final String GET_STRUCTURE = "getStructure";
public static final String GET_ALL = "getAllTrades";

@Column(nullable = false)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "xxx")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "xxxx", sequenceName = "xxxxS", allocationSize = 1)
private Long systemId;

@Id
@Column(nullable = false)
private Integer version;
 //////
```

And an descendant:

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns(
    {
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "systemId"),
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "version")
    }
)
public class YYY extends xxx {
 //////
```

I create an YYY instance and persiti is as i expect. After that i have per one row in each table in db:

```
fx = Persistence.invoke(new Persistence.Invoke<YYY>() {
            @Override
            public YYY run(EntityManager em) {
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new ClassPathResource("json/XXX_from.json").getFile()));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.print("File is not found");
                }
                YYYfx = (YYY) EntityConverter.getConverter(YYY.class).fromJson(reader);
                em.persist(fx);
                return fx;
            }
        });
```

So, after that fx is detached and as SPEC. sais i can make it persistent in another session by calling merge(), so call it but:

```
Persistence.invoke(new Persistence.Invoke<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object run(EntityManager em) {
        fx.setZZZ("A");
        em.merge(fx);
        return null;
    }
});
```

After that i have an another row in XXX and YYY tables with a new primary. It looks like provider takes fx as TRANSIENT not as DETACHED then it sais ok - it is a new object and i would insert it. 
I dont know what to do i ve lost 4 hours on such stupid case. Please help!

```
public class Persistence {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public static EntityManagerFactory getEmf() {
        return emf;
    }

    public void setEmf(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        Persistence.emf = emf;
    }

    public static <T> T invoke(Invoke<T> inv) {
        T result = null;
        EntityManager em = getEmf().createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
            try {
            result = inv.run(em);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public interface Invoke<T> {
        public T run(EntityManager em);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See API:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge(T)

> Returns: **the managed instance that the state was merged to**

So from your first call:

```
return em.persist(fx);
```

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/detach

> Detached objects can be attached to any EntityManager by using the
>   merge method:
>
> The content of the specified detached entity object is copied into an existing managed entity object with the same identity (i.e.
>   same type and primary key). If the EntityManager does not manage such
>   an entity object yet a new managed entity object is constructed. **The
>   detached object itself, however, remains unchanged and detached**.